# Attaching Email Automatically iOS

Tags: ios, email, csv

I have been building a survey app that users simply enter information in and its saved to a csv file. Im now at the stage where I need to attached the csv file within the app to an email address so when the user hits submit it sends the csv file in a email as an attachment automatically my code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {

    NSString *savedFilePath = @"../contact.csv";
    NSData *csvData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savedFilePath];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailcomposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailcomposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [mailcomposer addAttachmentData:csvData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"contact.csv"];
    [mailcomposer setToRecipients:@[@"email@here.co.uk"]];
    [mailcomposer setSubject:self.subject.text];
    [mailcomposer setMessageBody:self.message.text isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailcomposer animated:YES];
}

-(void) mailComposeController: (MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

This however doesnt attach the csv file... I have a feeling it may be to do with the line

```
 NSString *savedFilePath = @"../contact.csv";
```

However am not sure. If anyone can help please let me know... Im reaching breaking point with this one.

Comment: You need the full path the file, not relative. Where is the file located? In the documents directory ?

Comment: its located in library/application support/ ios simulator .... etc only thing is wont this change when being used on an iphone etc?

Comment: Is it a stance file, as in you app bundle or does you app create it and saves it some where. See my answer, here I assume that the file is in the document directory which is the most logical.

Comment: thats the full file location of where its being saved: Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/F2C92B8F-3F52-470F-AD64-DCA5DA75E935/Documents/results.csv

Comment: The my answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be in the fact you are loading the `NSData` with a relative path.

```
NSString *savedFilePath = @"../contact.csv";
NSData *csvData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savedFilePath];
```

Try the create the full path to the file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"result‌s.csv"];
NSData *csvData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savedFilePath];
```

Here I assume that the `contact.csv` is in the document directory.

Comment: yes the csv file is being saved to: Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/F2C92B8F-3F52-470F-AD64-DCA5DA75E935/Documents/results.csv

Comment: Just replace the code and I should work. What is happing is that I ask the system for the path to the document directory then add the file name. After which the `NSData` is loaded from the `savedFilePath`

Comment: Brilliant I will try it when i get in to test on my iphone (i cant send emails through the simulator..)

Comment: If tested in the simulator it should give you the mail composer with the attachment.

Comment: but on send you can check the flags.

Comment: I have just tested it on a real iPad the CSV now appears in the email composition page but doesn't actually get sent. It looks like it's attaching only an alias to the file rather than the file itself? So close but yet so far!

Comment: Hi rckoenes wondering if you could shed some light on my question above?

Comment: Hmm not really, If you seed to file the mail composer it should be there when you send it.

Comment: What do you mean by the term seed?

Comment: Sorry I meant sent the file.